# Problems retrieving data from POST in WCF

Tags: json, wcf, post

So I'm using a WCF service to insert data in a DB, for this purpose I send my data in a POST to my WCF service and collect it using a DataContract as so :

JSON data sent by POST

`{
    "data":
    {
        "subsidiarySid":"0",
        "storesid":"0",
        "date":"2018-06-15",
        "counters":
        [
            {
                "nation":"France",
                "count":"5"
            },
            {
                "nation":"France",
                "count":"5"
            }
        ]
    }
}`

The DataContract

```
[DataContract(Name ="data")]
    public class Count
    {
    [DataMember(Name ="subsidiarySid")]
    public string subsidiarySid;

    [DataMember(Name ="storeSid")]
    public string storeSid;

    [DataMember(Name = "date")]
    public string date;

    [DataMember(Name = "counters")]
    public IEnumerable<Counter> counters;
}

[DataContract]
public class Counter
{
    [DataMember(Name = "nationalitySid")]
    public string nationalitySid;

    [DataMember(Name = "count")]
    public string count;
}
```

Method in Interface

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "count_customers")]
string PostCount(Count count);
```

Problem is when I try to access this object I get a null...
Is my contract wrong or did I mess something elsewhere?
Also can I get rid of the "data{}" at the start of the json (like havig directly my "subsidiarySid etc at the root of the json)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my way after all, so I'm posting it as answer for future reference. What I did was to get the string attributes out of the DataContract (getting them by name in the OperationContract like this:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "count_customers")]
    string PostCount(string subsidiarySid, string storeSid, string date, IEnumerable<Counter> counters);
```

And the DataContract

```
[DataContract(Name = "counter")]
public class Counter
{
    [DataMember(Name = "nationalitySid")]
    public string nationalitySid;

    [DataMember(Name = "count")]
    public string count;
}
```

Just removing the "Name" attribute in DataContract definition permitted me to ommit the unnecessary "data:{}" layer.